# What is the difference between first-network and basic-network in the fabric 1.0 example?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I has tried Hyperledger Fabric 1.0's example, completed **first-network** and **fabcar** according to the official document, but I don't know what is the difference between **first-network** and **basic-network** ?
What I understand now is first-network has more peer objects, organizations 
 and enable TLS; basic-network has less peer objects, and use couchdb.

By the way, these difference will affect the certificate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**basic-network** sets up the minimum number of nodes required to develop chaincode and a basic application.  It only has a single peer and therefore a single organization as well.

**first-network** sets up a network which has multiple organizations and is designed to demonstrate a more real-world deployment topology.

The cryptographic material is different as **first-network** actually dynamically generates new crypto material whereas **basic-network** includes pre-generated crypto material.

Comment: I have another question, I notice **byfn.sh** 's code have a part about adding private key to **docker-compose-e2e.yaml**, but **docker-compose-e2e.yaml** seem to not be used on the **first-network**?

Answer (score 0):

Above answer is correct. Adding some notes to help out people who run into this.

The pre-generated (a.k.a. hard-coded in some sense) crypto material for **basic-network** can be found in [config](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release-1.3/basic-network/config) and [crypto-config](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release-1.3/basic-network/crypto-config) directories

**first-network** generates this crypto material by running `cryptogen` and `configtxgen` as can be seen in [byfn.sh](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.3/first-network/byfn.sh)

the commands used to generate the crypto material for **basic-network** can be found in [generate.sh](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.3/basic-network/generate.sh) in case you are wondering how they were created